# Why is pandas columns shape not correspond to the effective shape?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shapes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(2,64,64,3)
data = {'images': [data[0],data[1]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now if i try to print the shape of the 'image' column I get `(2,)` instead of `(2,64,64,3)`. This is the way I get the shape.

```
df['images'].shape
```

For example this code gives me the right answer

```
col = np.array(df['images'].values.tolist()).astype(np.float32)
col.shape
(2,64,64,3)
```

I wonder if there is a way to store data in a pandas column such that it if I try to call `shape` on that column it gives me `(2,64,64,3)`

Comment: From what I've seen so far, the data underlying a dataframe is either a 2d `numpy` array, or a set of `Series`, each using a 1d array.  The array dtypes may be numeric, but often are `object`, especially if they contain strings.  Object dtype can store lists and arrays, but the `pandas` handling of these is just as ugly as the `numpy` handling.

Comment: `pandas` used to have some sort of `panel` construction, made up of multiple dataframes.  But now it want's us to use `multiindexing`, what ever that is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to test nested arrays:

```
print (df['images'].apply(lambda x: x.shape))
0    (64, 64, 3)
1    (64, 64, 3)
Name: images, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, also if I chek `df['images'][0].shape` it gves me `(64,64,3)`. But why is the total shape not `(2,64,64,3)`???

Comment: @TommasoIaquinta - It is pandas, not numpy, so it compare elementwise if use `apply` like my solution

Comment: @TommasoIaquinta - `df['images'].shape` return `2`, because there are 2 rows